# Add modal panels to ArcGIS JavaScript Sandbox Template to display layer and parcel data

Tags: javascript, api, modal-dialog, arcgis

I want to edit [this Arcgis Sandbox Template](https://developers.arcgis.com/javascript/3/sandbox/sandbox.html?sample=search_suggestiontemplate) to have two modal panels positioned to the top and left of the map as seen below...

[image]

I want the panel on the left be linked to layers and the top modal panel be linked to the parcel info box as seen above.

Answer (score 0):

Add a border container with a center and  left and top region inside of a center region content pane by using div elements with proper CSS and organize content with layer list and info window modules.